# learn python the hard way ex 43

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am fairly new to python, currently going through learn python the hard way by zed shaw and I am at ex43 were I learning about making a game from classes.

The complete code is here http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        # be sure to print out the last scene
        current_scene.enter()
```

I am confused about this line

```
next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
```

From my understanding `current_scene` is actually not an object but a method `opening_scene()` from an object passed as the parameter `scene_map`, but the line is saying "from `current_scene` get the method `enter` and call it with no parameter".

How does this even work ?? any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`current_scene` is assigned the result of the `self.scene_map.opening_scene()` method call. So it doesn't refer to the method itself, but to whatever the method returned. That object has an `enter()` method.

Comment: ahh I see, so current method returns an object which have the method enter(). that makes sense. thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

`opening_scene` is the method, `opening_scene()` calls the method with no arguments. After `current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()`, `current_scene` holds whatever the method `opening_scene` returns. Which is, guessing from context, probably some kind of scene-object.